# how to calculate turned around datetime?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to calculate turned around statistic from table approval mention below with respect to query between creation datetime and Approval Datetime by using the MySQL query. Please help me for the output of my desired query.

```
ID  Creation Datetime        Approval Datetime       Year   Month   Days    Hour    Min     Sec
    (Datatype Datetime)     (Datatype Datetime)         

1   2020-12-24 12:24:56 PM  2021-01-08 10:43:30 AM    0      0       24     22      18       34
```

```
Select 
Creation Datetime, 
Approval Datetime, 
Approval Datetime- Creation Datetime As Year,
Approval Datetime- Creation Datetime As Months,
Approval Datetime- Creation Datetime As Hour,
Approval Datetime- Creation Datetime As Min,
Approval Datetime- Creation Datetime As Sec
From tbl_approval;
```

Comment: Store dates using a proper date data type.

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE` on your text dates, then follow the duplicate link.